# Laravel relations post has many likes

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

```
        $post = Post::where('reply_to', 0)->skip(0)->take(10)->orderBy('pid', 'desc')->get();

        return Response::json(array(
            'status' => 200,
            'posts' => $post->toArray()
        ), 200);
```

I am suppose to display the posts and within the posts have an array info of who has liked it.

Returning it in json.

My Post model contains

```
public function likes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Like', 'pid', 'pid');
}
```

So my problem is I cant manage to do this format. I'm kinda lost.

JSON:

```
{
    status 200
    posts  pid
           uid
           content
           likes
               uid

           post 2
           likes
               uid
}
```

Models

```
Post
    pid
    uid
    content

Like
    lid (like id)
    pid (post id)
    uid (user id)
```

Suggestions and help is very welcome

---

question is how to achieve the output I was trying to get. Where I return a json format of all the posts and inside each post have an array of the likes if the post has any. Its an API.

Comment: dont understand...what's your question?

Comment: @EduardoStuart question is how to achieve the output I was trying to get. Where I return a json format of all the posts and inside each post have an array of the likes if the post has any. Its an API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test this..but..try:

Post Model:

```
public function likes(){
   $this->hasMany('Like','post_id');
}
```

Like Model:

```
public function post(){
   $this->belongsTo('Post','post_id');
}
```

Response:

```
$posts = Post::with('likes')->get();

Response::json( $posts->toJson() );
```

---

Try this... With the `likes` id only:

```
Post::with(array('likes'=>function($query){
   $query->select('id');
}))->get();
```

Comment: What if I wanted to include all the post even if it doesn't have any likes? The response is suppose to be an api. where if its called it gets the 10 most recent posts data. but I will try your answer first. Thanks :)

Comment: With a little edits on the code it did just what I wanted. Will accept the answer asap. Lastly just a side question, how do I just show the uid from the likes, instead of giving all columns from likes?

Comment: I tried the edit but now the likes doesn't contain anything even though it should. anyways i edited ID to UID because thats my column.

Comment: @eduardo-stuart 
I need to return boolean if relation has data instead of likes response in JSON.
Please help me
return Post::with('likes', 'PostedBy', 'cat', 'tags', 'comments')->latest()->paginate(6);